Content Disposition break the JSP Request
I am working on adding functionality download functionality to a Java app using JSP and Struts 1.2.9 for UI.
Basically, I am fetching a list of data from the DB and then generate a CSV file from the data.
Currently, I have mapped a new UI button to a new Struts action. The download action class does the following:
public class DownloadCSVAction extends AbstractAction {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
    // some code to fetch the content
    response.setContentType("text/csv");

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
    String currentTime = format.format(new Date());
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = "attachment; filename=report_" + currentTime + ".csv";
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
    
    // some code to put content in CSV string format
    printWriter.close();

    // Unsetting Content-Disposition header to remove file download from the response after download
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setHeader(headerKey, "");

    return mapping.findForward("success");
  }    
}

Now this code is downloading the file just fine. However, once the file is downloaded, anything else I click in the UI results in an error
12:14:37,216 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-13) UT005023: Exception handling request to /SecurityLibrary/DownloadCSVInit.do: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010019: Response already commited
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.resetBuffer(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:732)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.resetBuffer(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:495)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:167)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:147)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085)
    at ...MainRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(MainRequestProcessor.java:345)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
    at ...MainRequestProcessor.process(MainRequestProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at ...MainServlet.process(MainServlet.java:101)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)

I tried solving my issue using:

Error : IllegalStateException in Java. Cannot forward after response has been committed
after download a image ,i want to redirect on another page, but not able to
https://www.javatpoint.com/downloading-file-from-the-server-in-jsp

but nothing helped.

After response is committed you cannot do any  results in Struts 1.x.
You need to
return null;

from the action execute method to prevent processing ActionForward.
// some code to put content in CSV string format
printWriter.close();

// After these lines
return null;



This fixes the error thrown by this specific action class. But the UI has other buttons such as "Next Page", "Prev Page" or "Return to search" which aren't working. They are failing because printWriter.close() has already dispatched the response. What could be the solution for it?

Other buttons should not map to this action. They may be used to submit another request.
